# Getting count of number of rows of data retrieved from several SQL Tables on an SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on an SQL Query which returns several rows of data from SQL tables on SQL Server using joins. But I just want the Query to return count of number of rows of data that is returned by following SQL Query

```
SELECT  C.ContactID,
 C.FirstName,
 C.LastName,
 SP.SalesPersonID,
 SP.CommissionPct,
 SP.SalesYTD,
 SP.SalesLastYear,
 SP.Bonus,
 ST.TerritoryID,
 ST.Name,
 ST.[Group],
 ST.SalesYTD
FROM Person.Contact C
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP
 ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST 
 ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
ORDER BY ST.TerritoryID, C.LastName
```

How to get the number of rows the above query returns. I would do it easily with the help of an SQL View but I don't want to create a view on the server as I just have read permissions to the database.

May I know a better way to solve considering the restrictions I have on the database?

Comment: Why can't you just make another query that returns `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person.Contact C INNER JOIN...`? That's the lightest alternative to making a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this as two queries. One like you listed, and the other with a `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM Person.Contact C
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP
    ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST 
    ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
ORDER BY ST.TerritoryID, C.LastName
```

This will return a scalar result, so you don't have to waste unnecessary bandwidth at any point. But it really depends on how you expect to use it. Dave's answer is appropriate if you need to pull all the records back no matter what, but if that's the case I would just check your `List<>.Count` or `[].Length` properties.

You could also add in the column `COUNT(*) OVER() AS [ResultCount]`, but remember that that will return the same value for every row. Again, it just depends how you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@@ROWCOUNT` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)). It returns the number of rows affected (selected, updated, deleted, etc) of the previous query.

```
SELECT  C.ContactID,
 C.FirstName,
 C.LastName,
 SP.SalesPersonID,
 SP.CommissionPct,
 SP.SalesYTD,
 SP.SalesLastYear,
 SP.Bonus,
 ST.TerritoryID,
 ST.Name,
 ST.[Group],
 ST.SalesYTD
FROM Person.Contact C
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson SP
 ON C.ContactID = SP.SalesPersonID
FULL OUTER JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory ST 
 ON ST.TerritoryID = SP.TerritoryID
ORDER BY ST.TerritoryID, C.LastName

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: It just returns error in ORDER BY CLAUSE  Unable to Parse Query Text

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the query itself. Does `ORDER BY ST.TerritoryID, C.LastName` have correct column names?

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can add "select @@rowcount" as the next command after your query.  An alternative is you could group by all your fields and add a count(*) in the select clause.